# Why SearchBar color changed while editing?

Tags: ios, search, searchbar

I have UISearchBar, i setted correctly desired color on it. 
**Like in below picture**:

[image]

When i start to writing on searchBar(while start editing) searchBar color changed. 
**Like in below picture**:

[image]

***I want to searchBar color do not change when start writing on searchBar.
How can i ensure that?***

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this problem. My solution like below:

```
+ (void)removeUISearchBarBackgroundInViewHierarchy:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *subview in [view subviews]) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchBarBackground")]) {
            [subview removeFromSuperview];
            break; //To avoid an extra loop as there is only one UISearchBarBackground
        } else {
            [self removeUISearchBarBackgroundInViewHierarchy:subview];
        }
    }}
```